# What is the difference between save() method and persist() method in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, transactions, save, persist

I found some answers at stackoverflow,it says "persist() also guarantees that it will not execute an INSERT statement if it is called outside of transaction boundaries. This is useful in long-running conversations with an extended Session/persistence context. ". What's the meaning of "outside of transaction boundaries"? It means the persist() method is called before "tx = session.beginTransaction()" or after "tx.commit()" ? And I tested like that, but persist() method also execute an INSERT statement and insert date into database. Help me, please.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I posted some mock testing on this and you can find it here 
[Whats the difference between persist() and save() in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097679/whats-the-difference-between-persist-and-save-in-hibernate/17867874#17867874)

Thanks,
Deivanayagam Senthil