# Hibernate Duplicate values when inserting data

Tags: hibernate

when inserting into the database using persist function in hibernate session

it sometimes duplicates rows , is it a problem with hibernate ?

```
currentSession.persist(cloudUser);
currentSession.flush();

tx.commit();
```

Comment: Try to gather logs of what Hibernate doing [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/print-query-string-in-hibernate-with-parameter-values). And provide here more information about what you exactly doing. Hibernate itself is fine in such trivial cases.

Answer (score 1):

persist() method doesn't guarantee that the identifier value will be assigned to the persistent instance immediately, the assignment might happen at flush time.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/09/difference-hibernate-save-vs-persist-and-saveOrUpdate.html#ixzz2lpDfeIh8

Answer (score 0):

You have two methods to persist your object. save () and persist()... While taking decision  ,**ID generation strategy** also should be taken into the consideration. Save method will fire insert query immediately but persist() will not..

Clcik [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994098/hibernate-persist-vs-save/19996277#19996277)