# Bi-directional one-to-many relationship does not work

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have made an application that displays a lot of questions from my database. For this I have made a question entity. I want to be able to "report" a question for being poor/good and so on, so for this I made a feedback entity.

The relationship between these would be: one question may have many feedbacks, and one feedback belongs to one question.

The problem is that when I save the question feedback instance it all maps perfectly in the database, but when I open a question and loops through all the feedbacks none of the feedbacks added is displayed. In order to have them displayed I need to re-deploy the web application.

Why does this happen?

**For readability I only show the parts involved**

**QuestionFeedback entity**

```
public class QuestionFeedback implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private Question question;
    ....

    public void setQuestion(Question question) {
        this.question = question;

        if (!question.getFeedbacks().contains(this)) {
            question.getFeedbacks().add(this);
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

**Question entity**

```
@Entity
public class Question implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<QuestionFeedback> feedbacks;

    public Question() {
        feedbacks = new ArrayList<QuestionFeedback>();
    }

    public void addFeedback(QuestionFeedback questionFeedback) {

        if (!getFeedbacks().contains(questionFeedback)) {
            getFeedbacks().add(questionFeedback);
        }

        if (questionFeedback.getQuestion() != this) {
            questionFeedback.setQuestion(this);
        }
    }
}
```

**Backing bean for the report page**

The question entity is already retrieved from the database.

```
public String flag() {
    questionFeedback.setQuestion(question);
    questionFeedbackService.persist(questionFeedback);

    return "index";
}
```

**DAO class**

```
public void persist(QuestionFeedback questionFeedback) {
    entityManager.persist(questionFeedback);
}
```

Comment: If I correctly understand your question, this seems to be a transactional problem as data is correctly stored in the database, correct? If true, it must relate to your entity manager usage (and configuration)...

Comment: That is probably true yes. If I refresh the question entity in the find method of my DAO, it works. Seems like it caches it or something. I am using Glassfish with container-managed transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple instance of having a dirty session.

Although these can be caused by all sorts of issues, there are usually 2 simple things to keep in mind that will make it very easy to track this bug down .

First you must always remember that, when we **persist** our data in JPA/hibernate , we don't necessarily have any gaurantee that the transaction has completed in the database.  The true meaning of the "persist" method is a common source of errors and questions, make sure you fully understand it and how it relates to your business logic.   :

[What's the advantage of persist() vs save() in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862680/whats-the-advantage-of-persist-vs-save-in-hibernate)

Second, after you have gauranteed that the transaction has been completed and data has been saved, you can use the **EntityManager.refresh** method to update the state of any objects from the database.

Comment: That is probably correct, because if I refresh the question entity when after I have used the `EntityManager.find()` it displays all feedbacks. I am using container-managed transaction and Glassfish so shouldn't the persistencecontext flush when the method where my `EntityManager.persist()` ends? And doesn't `EntityManager.find()` fetch the entity from the database? Or are there some cache or something.

Comment: This works: `public Question find(Long id) {
        Question q = entityManager.find(Question.class, id);
        entityManager.refresh(q);
        return q;}`

Comment: And it also works to merge the question when I persist the question feedback instance. I don't understand it though.

Comment: Hmmm... I cant fully grasp all the details.  But - I do not believe that your persistance context automatically flushes every time you do a persist.  Persist only tells the session that, at some point, the transaction is to be commited - I dont think it forces an immediate commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the JPA cache through the following code:

```
 em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
```

For the record, I always flush after persisting data. Even though your database has the data, I would just try this.

```
public String flag() {
   questionFeedback.setQuestion(question);
   questionFeedbackService.persist(questionFeedback);
   questionFeedbackService.flush();

   return "index";
}
```

Comment: So there is a JPA cache that keeps it as well as the persistence context "cache"?

Comment: JPA essentially has two levels of caching. The evictAll() function clears the second level cache or L2 cache. See link for further explanation of JPA caching: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/caroljmcdonald/archive/2009/08/21/jpa-caching