# Get generated id from a sequence before hibernate saves the object

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, orm

How do I get the generated ID for an object before hibernate saves it. Here's the code:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="MY_SEQ", sequenceName="MY_SEQ", allocationSize=1 )
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="MY_SEQ")
private long id;
```

Is there any way that I can do this without using a select on currval('MY_SEQ') ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try session.persist() ? persist will put the object into session but does not save it into the db yet, so, there could be a good chance that it will generate the sequence for you.

Comment: I'll take back my answer.. persist does not give you generated id immediately http://stackoverflow.com/a/5862722/258741

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the JPA @SequenceGenerator along with the legacy Hibernate identifiers will give you the [SequenceHiLoGenerator](http://vladmihalcea.com/from-jpa-to-hibernates-legacy-and-enhanced-identifier-generators/) that applies a [HI/LO optimization algorithm](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-hilo-algorithm/) anyway.

But for Sequences, the actual identifier value is applied [during flush-time](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/), so you won't get the actual value until the session gets flushed (a manual flush or the commit-time flush).

For IDENITY generator, you get the identifier generated prior to flushing, but that disables JDBC batching so it's not a silver-bullet either.

If you want full control, you need to resort to assigned identifiers and [UUID surrogate keys](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-and-uuid-identifiers/) are perfect for this job.