# How to return Auto Generated Id in Spring Boot with Hibernate

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to `Spring` framework and trying to implement a simple `CRUD` application in `spring boot` with `MySQL` as database. Everything is working fine.
I have the `Auto Increment` enabled on `Id` field in the database. I am using `EntityManager.persist()` method to save the data in database and it is working fine. Now I want to return the `auto generated`Id back to the client as response of `POST` method but `EntityManager.persist()`return type is `void`.

Can anyone help me that how I can return the Id back?

Comment: The id is in the persisted entity. Just do `getId()` on the entity and it will have an id.

Answer (score 1):

the id is guaranteed after flush operation or when the transaction is completed.

```
    em.persist(employee)
    em.flush();
    long id = employee.getId();
```

for more details read

[What's the advantage of persist() vs save() in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862680/whats-the-advantage-of-persist-vs-save-in-hibernate)