# grails object persistence vs spring mvc hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, grails

In grails controller I prefer using:

```
def abc = new ClassName(field1:params?.firstRequestParameter,
                         field2:params?.secondRequestParameter)
if(!abc.save()){
   abc.errors.each{ it.println }
}
```

for saving an object in the database.

What is its equivalent methodology for saving an object in spring mvc & Hibernate?

Comment: Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862680/whats-the-advantage-of-persist-vs-save-in-hibernate

Comment: I've edited my question. why is it still showing duplicate and why I am also not allowed to ask more question?