# What exactly happens when I use session.save instead of session.persist?

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I know this is a very common topic. I have also read a lot of blogs and post related to it, but most of them just tell the difference that `save()` returns an identifier and `persist()` has return type of void. Both belong to the package `org.hibernate`.

I have read the following posts too:

- *[Difference between save() and persist() in Hibernate](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-save-and-persist-in-hibernate)*
- *[What's the difference between session.persist() and session.save() in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862680/whats-the-difference-between-session-persist-and-session-save-in-hibernate)*
- *[What are the differences between the different saving methods in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161224/what-are-the-differences-between-the-different-saving-methods-in-hibernate/54907032#54907032)*

I have a database as follows.

[image: Database]

For those people who do not use [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA), `instructor_id` serves as a foreign key in the table `course` which references `instructor(id)` and similarly for the other table as well.

I was trying to save courses to an instructor in the following way:

```
session.beginTransaction();

// get the instructor from the database
int theId = 1;
Instructor tempInstructor =
    session.get(Instructor.class, theId);

// create some courses
Course tempCourse1 = new Course("Java");
Course tempCourse2 = new Course("Maven");
tempInstructor.add(tempCourse1, tempCourse2);

session.save(tempInstructor);

// Commit transaction
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

The related entry in `Instructor` class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "instructor",
            cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
private List<Course> courses;
```

The `add` method in `Instructor`-

```
public void add(Course... tempCourse) {

    if (courses == null) {
        courses = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    for (Course course : tempCourse) {
        courses.add(course);
        course.setInstructor(this);
    }


}
```

The related entry in `Course` class:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name = "instructor_id")
private Instructor instructor; // Associated Entity
```

When I try to save the instructor with `session.save(tempInstructor);`, none of the courses are saved with the instructor when I use `session.save()`, but when I use `session.persist()` both the courses are also saved. I know that `save()` returns an identifier and `INSERTS` object immediately then why is it not saving the courses?

I also read somewhere

> save() is not good in
> a long-running conversation with an extended Session/persistence
> context.

What all happens when I call save and why aren't the objects saved?

Comment: Try calling `Session.flush` right after `save`

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `tempCourse1` and `tempCourse2` are in a detached state, so to make a relation you need to persist them.

Both `save` and `persist` doing the same thing, but `save` is Hibernate's API and `persist` is a part of the JPA specification.

On your entity, you have `CascadeType.PERSIST` which relates only to the `persist` method. To make `save` behave the same, you should add `org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType#SAVE_UPDATE` to your `ManyToOne` annotation.