# Hibernate session.get(..) method not hitting database

Tags: hibernate

Newbie to Hibernate. 
I am just trying to understand `session.get()` method "avoiding a database hit if the object is already cached"

```
List<Employee> employees1 = session.createCriteria(Employee.class).list();

Main main = new Main();
try {
    synchronized (main) {
        main.wait(10000);
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

Employee  employees2 = (Employee)session.get(Employee.class, new Long(1));
System.out.println(employees2.getFirstname() + " , "+ employees2.getLastname() );
```

1. In the first line i got a record with firstname as 'Kevin' lastname as 'Papad'
2. While it was waiting i went to database and changed firstname to 'steve'
3. `session.get()` is not hitting database and getting me values firstname as 'Kevin' lastname as 'Papad' which is WRONG.

I kept wait because anybody can change values in database meanwhile (between 1st and 3rd steps above), in that case how can i get correct values in 3rd step? i.e., firstname to 'steve'

What changes do i need to make to my code?

Please correct me if my understanding/approach is wrong.

Comment: The details can be understood from the thread 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044963/hibernate-3-6-session-get-vs-session-load . The thread has pitfalls of get and load methods.

Comment: Moreover , hibernate session is not Threadsafe and as per api recomendation it is not advisable to keep the session open for long time , it should be opened and closed after each piece of work.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `session.refresh(Object)` with the entity you want to be reloaded. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-loading

Note: There is a warning in [Javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html#refresh%28java.lang.Object%29) about usage of this, see this [thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=974544) for a discussion.

Comment: so, every time do i need to use session.refresh(Object)  if i call session.get() ?

Comment: If you can't know whether that entity is loaded and you have to have the latest version of it, than i think yes. By the way you don't have to call `get()` in your example. You loaded the whole table with the first line. So you can just iterate over the list and check for the one with `id == 1`.