# difference between getReference() and load()

Tags: java, hibernate, session, jpa

In Hibernate 4.3 ,  `load()`  from  `session` returns the proxy object with lazy loading and `get()` returns the object if it exists or `null` if it doesn't. But [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d5e947) and [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d5e956) its mentioned that `getReference()` returns a proxy object and `load()` returns an object with initialized data.
On Further googling i realized that these methods are from ***IdentifierLoadAccess Interface***. so my questions are

1. Is this `getReference()` is functionally equal to `load()` from **session** and this `load()` is equal to `get()` from `session`?
2. Is this Interface is part of JPA specification? or from Hibernate Native API?
3. What is the need for these methods when they have these functionalities are already covered in session interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `EntityManager#getReference()` is functionally equal to `session#load()`. This can be verified by the hibernate 's EntityManager implementation ( `AbstractEntityManagerImpl`) which delegates the work to session#load().

   `session#load()` and `session#get()` have some difference in behaviour . For details , please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044963/hibernate-3-6-session-get-vs-session-load/8046695#8046695).
2. `IdentifierLoadAccess` is under the package `org.hibernate` . So it is Hibernate native API . All interfaces defined by JPA specification are under the package `javax.persistence`.
3. JPA are standard Java API for persistence which means if your application only uses JPA API ,  theoretically , it is portable between different JPA providers. You application would work even you change to use other JPA provider only switch to other JavaEE application server.

Answer (score 2):

The package of `IdentifierLoadAccess` is `org.hibernate`. It's thus not part of the JPA spec. Otherwise, it would be under `javax.persistence`.

`IdentifierLoadAccess.getReference()` is, as the example suggests, equivalent to `EntityManager.getReference()`, and also to the old, badly named `Session.load()`.

`IdentifierLoadAccess.load()` is, as the example suggests, equivalent to `EntityManager.find()`, and also to the `Session.get()`.

As far as I understand, this `IdentifierLoadAccess` interface and the methods it contains are useful to provide a consistent way to load/getReference to entities between IDs and simple natural IDs (and to a lesser extent, natural IDs). See all the methods starting by `by` in the Session api doc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @JB-Nizet. Any thoughts on the third question?

Comment: I amended the answer.