# hibernate createQuery vs get

Tags: java, hibernate

What advantages does `get` have over `createQuery`?

I can see there might be a slight performance improvement in not having to parse the HQL, but is there any other major advantage to using get over createQuery?

Answer (score 5):

First, it's much quicker to type, is much more readable, and expresses the intent clearly: get an entity by its ID. And it's basically impossible to make an error, whereas you could have a typo in your HQL query.

Regarding performance, the main advantage is that it executes a select statement only if the entity is not in the session cache yet. An HQL query will be executed every time. And if you have a second-level cache, `get()` will avoid executing a query completely if the entity is already in the second-level cache.

Comment: So, according to this, you're not right about the performance of 'get': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370482/whats-the-advantage-of-load-vs-get-in-hibernate. Looks like you're actually talking about the performance of 'load'.

Comment: Nope. `get()` looks if the entity is in the session cache. If it is already, it returns it. Else, it executes a SQL query to load it,  puts it in the session cache, and returns it. `load()` checks if the entity is in the session cache. If it is already, it returns it. Else, it creates a lazy proxy, without even checking if the object exists in the database, and returns this proxy. Why don't you check it by yourself? Turn SQL logging on, and experiment.

Comment: Interesting distinction. Where can I read more about this? The places I'm finding information on 'get' seem to all mention that it "always hits the database". Are they all repeating the same misinformation?

Answer (score 0):

`get()` uses directly session to retrieve objects.

- get() only useful when you want to load an object i.e. SQL SELECT.
- Like save() and persist() result in an SQL INSERT, delete() in an SQL DELETE and update() or merge() in an SQL UPDATE.
- limited control and we need specify an entity that we need to extract.

`createQuery()`  uses HQL

- Using HQL we can write all CRUD queries.
- give more control we can specify HQL(SQL like) clauses.
- HQL is the own query language of hibernate and it is used to perform bulk operations on hibernate programs
- An object oriented form of SQL is called HQL.
- Here we are going to replace table column names  with POJO class variable names and table names with POJO class names in order to get HQL commands
- Sometimes it is very hard to write with other alternatives. Using HQL we can implement faster.