# What's the difference between query.uniqueResult() vs session.load() in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Can anyone tell me what's the difference between this code:

```
// This following method checks if there is an open session
// and if yes - returns it,  if not - opens a new session. 
Session session = getSession();
Query query = session.createQuery("from Entity e where e.id = 1");
Entity object = (Entity)query.uniqueResult();
```

and this:

```
 Session session = getSession();
 Entity object = (Entity)session.load(Entity.class, new Integer(1));
```

Does the first method return a proxy object? And if I call it again does it hit the database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the advantage of load() vs get() in Hibernate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370482/whats-the-advantage-of-load-vs-get-in-hibernate)

Comment: It's not exact duplicate, but accepted answer answers your question too.

Comment: @Azodious it's not about query.uniqueResualt() it's about session.get() i think they have different behavior

Comment: doesn't explanation of `load` in that question answer your question? `uniqueResult` can return `null` but `load` will never.

Answer (score 11):

There are some differences (as of *Hibernate* 5.2.6).

`session.load()`

- It only searchs by id assuming that the Entity exists
- It will ALWAYS return a “**proxy**” (Hibernate term) without hitting the database. In Hibernate, *proxy* is an object with the given identifier value, its properties are **not initialized** yet, it just looks like a temporary fake object.
- Use this only to retrieve an instance that you assume exists, where non-existence would be an *ObjectNotFoundException*.

`query.uniqueResult()`

- You can query with complex conditions, not only by the id
- Convenience method to return a single instance that matches the query, or `null` if the query returns no results.
- It will return an entity with its collection **initialized** or not depending on the *FetchType*.

Comment: does query.uniqueResult() return a proxy object ? if i call it for secound time for same query it will hit the database ?

Comment: It will hit the database or not depending on the cache configuration, you can configure second level cache for the entire class or only for some attributes. I am not sure about the proxy object, in my understunding query.uniqueResult() will return a proxy object if FetchType is lazy.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#load-java.lang.Class-java.io.Serializable- it could be persistent instance or proxy. not always proxy